# How to verify sender email address is really the one displayed?

Tags: email, authentication, email-client, cryptography, phishing

.Hi experts,

There are ways to fake the sender email address as I have read.
Meaning that if you receive an email, then the"from" email address visible on the frontend in your email client can in reality differ from the one which actually (technically) sent the email.

How can I check that the visible email address=the one from which the email was actually sent? When I have access to the **email header**.  What should I look for exactly in the email header?

Thank you

Comment: Emails are like the post. The only way to know if it is genuine is if you are expecting it and can verify the sender by a means not contained within the communication.

Comment: It is helpful to check the sending server. This week there was some "order confirmation" from a German sender, that was sent by an ".in" server.